# Function as NPObject - how to get its signature?

Tags: javascript, npapi

My NPAPI plugin receives a Javascript function as NPObject.
Is there a way to get this function's signature, or at least, the number of parameters it requires?

Thank you.

Comment: @dda it's JavaScript, not Javascript you can see this anywhere you look.

Comment: Also, why on earth would you change "Thank you!" to Thank you."? Fixing grammar mistakes is one thing; pointlessly changing the tone of someone's sign-off is just rude.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike C++, JavaScript is [dynamically typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Dynamic): you just call the function and rely on it to handle what you pass in.

While there is [`Function.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) to get the number of named arguments, differing behavior based on this breaks approaches like:

- handling different argument counts by checking for the arguments being defined
- using the [`arguments` array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of arguments using such code:

```
function MyFunc(a, b, c) {
     //some stuff here...
}

var num = MyFunc.length;
alert("number of arguments: " + num);
```

[Test case](http://jsfiddle.net/kEL4M/).

Other than that not much you can get outside the function itself, JavaScript does not have types so you can't know what type of arguments the function is expecting.

Comment: That easy? Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.